# My website dont keep his style in minimized internet

Tags: html, css

I am working on my laptop in VSCode, after I make my site, I go to stylizing him and after I make this after my pleasure, when I minimize Google, it doesn't keep his resolution.

[This is full screen on google chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFAX6.png)

[And this is google chrome minimized.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In7ba.png)

What could I do for websites keep his style as I put him in full screen?

**HTML:**

```
<!--HTML SOURCE--!>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
    <title> </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
 awesome.min.css">
</head>
<header> 
    <div class="navbar"> 
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PROJECT PAGE/proiecte.html">Proiecte</a></li>
        <li><a href="/STAFF PAGE/staff.html">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/CONTACT PAGE/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    <img class="background" src="casey-horner-O0R5XZfKUGQ-unsplash.jpg">
 </div>
 </header>


 <body>   
    <h1 class="titlu"> Titlu </h1> 
<div>
<img class="h" src="Other-html-5-icon.png"> 
<img class="c" src="CSS.png">
</div> 

<div class="cards"> 
<img class="x" src="pngegg.png">  
<img class="y" src="pngegg.png"> 
<img class="z" src="pngegg.png">
</div>

    <div class="faicon">
    <i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="textfaicon"> 
    <h1> Economisire </h1>
    <p><b>Economisesti timp si mai ales,<br>
        economisesti bani! Cat astepti sa<br> 
        cauti o echipa care sa iti poata <br>
        crea site-ul dorit, noi iti suntem<br>
        aproape. Cerem foarte putin pentru<br>
        serviciile pe care le oferim!</b>
    </p>
   </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
  /* CSS */ 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');

 body{ 
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0px; 
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 }

 * {
 box-sizing: 
 border-box;
 }


 .background { 
 position: absolute; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 120%; 
 padding-left: 0%;
 padding-bottom: 10%; 
 -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 }

 .titlu{ 
 position: relative; 
 color: white;
 padding-left: 45%;
 padding-top: 15%;
 font-size: 50px;
 }

 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: rgb(31, 37, 77); 
 opacity: 100%; 
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 }

 li {
 float: left;
 }

 li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 }

 li a:hover {
   background-color: #111;
   }

  .active {
   background-color: #0c3a55;
  }

 .h{ 
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px; 
 bottom: -270px; 
 margin-bottom: 10%;
 padding: 0%; 
 left: 8%;
 }

.c{ 
position: relative;
height: 300px; 
width: 220px; 
bottom: -100px; 
margin-bottom: 0%; 
padding: 0%; 
left: 50%; 
}

.x{ 
position: relative; 
height: 500px; 
width: 250px; 
left: 10%;     
}

.y{ 
position: relative; 
height: 500px; 
width: 250px; 
left: 10%; 
}

.z{ 
position: relative; 
height: 500px; 
width: 250px; 
left: 10%; 
}

.cards{ 
position: relative;
bottom: -150px; 
left: 13%;
padding: 0%; 
margin: 0%;
width: 200;
}

 .faicon{ 
 position: relative; 
 text-align: center;
 right: 2%;
 bottom: 290px;
 font-size: 40px; 
 }

 .textfaicon{ 
 text-align: center;
 position:relative; 
 color:#0c3a55; 
 font-size: 10px;
 bottom: 280px;
 right: 2%;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
```

Comment: If you want the site to just scale down when the screen does, you can remove the meta viewport tag. This isn't advisable though. [Check out how to create responsive websites using CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries).

Comment: Try to make every dimension relative - a % rather than using px values (other than when you really don't want something to get too small, usually a font size) so that as the window size increases or decreases everything moves together. If having done this you then find your design doesn't work well on a small screen size, then start to introduce media queries.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest you to try [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), it will make your page responsive to all types of devices and you will write less CSS. Good luck.